# Update specific row based on string

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, cursor

I'm new to ArcPy. I am attempting to find the string 'Unknown' and update the 'Comments' field, that indicates which field contains the 'Unknown' string for that row. I was attempting to use UpdateCursor but it populates every row under comments rather then just the specific row that contains the string.

```
points = r'C:/ex.shp'
fields= ['COMMENTS', 'COUNTY', 'STATUS']

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(points, fields) as cursor:
  for row in cursor:
    if row[1] == 'UNKNOWN':
      row[0] = 'County is Unknown'
    if row[2] == 'UNKNOWN':
      row[0] = 'Status is Unknown'
    cursor.updateRow(row)
```

[image]

I understand this won't work since it is checking/updating each row for that specified field. Can someone point me in the right direction on how one would do this properly?

Comment: If you're searching for "Unknown", then then "UNKNOWN" won't match it (case sensitive comparison). Always use 4 spaces for your indent rule (see [PEP 8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/)). You don't handle the case where *both* are UNKNOWN.

Comment: You are updating all rows since `cursor.updateRow(row)` is not indentated to match the ifs

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import arcpy

fc = r"C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp\ArcGISProTemp10292\Untitled\Default.gdb\points1"
fields = ["COMMENTS","COUNTY","STATUS"]

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, fields) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        
        c = row.count("UNKNOWN") #Count how many times UNKNOWN occur in the row
        if c==0:
            result = "Missing" #If 0, set COMMENT to Missing
        elif c==1:
            result = f"{fields[row.index('UNKNOWN')]} is Unknown" #If once, fetch the field name from field list using index
        elif c==2:
            result = f"{fields[1]} and {fields[2]} are both Unknown"
        else:
            raise ValueError(f"Cant handle this row: {row}") #Just in case something went wrong, stop the execution
         
        row[0] = result
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```

[index, count](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your code is work. You should use `elif` after first `if` condition and as Vince said, you should add one more condition.
I think, your problem is – to view the result you must reopen the table.